# Strange Pokémon attack names in a German translation

Tags: translation, meaning, word-formation

While playing Pokémon in German, I came across a few attack names (usually with the *-er* ending) that I wasn't able to find in the dictionary. In the English version of the game these names just seem to be normal nouns/verbs.

- [Fuchtler](http://www.pokewiki.de/Fuchtler) (Thrash)
- [Einigler](http://www.pokewiki.de/Einigler) (Defense Curl)
- [Walzer](http://www.pokewiki.de/Walzer) (Rollout)
- [Lockduft](http://www.pokewiki.de/Lockduft) (Sweet Scent)
- [Abgangsbund](http://www.pokewiki.de/Abgangsbund) (Destiny Bond)

Of what words/morphemes are these attack names composed? Do they mean exactly the same thing in German as in English?

Answer (score 11):

X-er normally means "someone doing X" (backen -> Bäcker etc.), but is here used for the action itself.

- Fuchtler < fuchteln "to brandish, to wave about". Close enough, "Prügler" would have been too strong.
- Einigler < ein-igeln "to curl up like a hedgehog". Pretty good translation, as "to curl" is difficult to translate.
- Walzer < walzen "to roll, to steamroll, to flatten". Also a pretty good translation.
- Lockduft < locken "to lure, to tempt" + Duft "scent". "Süßduft" would have sounded awkward, so it's a good alternative
- Abgangsbund < abgehen "to leave -> to kick the bucket" + Bund (same word as English "bond", but different usage). A direct translation would have been "Schicksalsbund", but the translator chose to illustrate the mechanics of the move.

So they are all not literal translations, but good choices.

Comment: Worth a look for [other ways in which -er builds nouns](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-er)

Comment: Is "fuchteln" like hitting repeatedly the enemy with your waving arms/tentacles?

Comment: @user9224: It's like waving arms/tentacles a lot. "To flail" is also a good translation. The hitting is more or less accidental. I don't know how the actual attacks look like.

Comment: +1 for Einigler, I never understood what it meant :D

Comment: A »Fuchtel« is a short sword ("broadsword" in english). With this weapon you can make very quick movements that confuses your opponent. This is why the german verb "fuchteln" means "making fast movements with your hands that seem to have no sense". And "Hans steht unter Annas Fuchtel" means that Hans has to do everything what Anna wants, because it is her who (in a figurative sense) carries the sword to oppress Hans.